# What does appendChild function in fine-uploader do

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I am trying out fine-uploader's library. I am getting the following console error whenever I run their traditional UI and PHP server code:

```
templating.js:638 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at qq.Templating.render (templating.js:638)
at new qq.FineUploader (uploader.js:162)
at (index):87
```

What could be the issue (Sorry question may not be detailed but i figure anyone who has interacted with the library gets it)